# Woocommerce custom coupon type with custom discount always return 0;

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

what I am trying to do is creating custom coupon type with custom programmatically discount in woocommerce using hooks. This what my code looks like

```
//add new coupon type called "custom_discount"
function custom_discount_type( $discount_types ) {
    $discount_types['custom_discount'] =__( 'custom discount', 'woocommerce' );
    return $discount_types;
    }

// add the hooks
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_discount_types', 'custom_discount_type',10, 1);

//function to get coupon amount for "custom_discount"
function woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount($discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon) {
        if ($coupon->type == 'custom_discount'){ //if $coupon->type == 'fixed_cart' or 'percent' or 'fixed_product' or 'percent_product' The code Works
            $discount = 85;
            return $discount;
            } else {
             return $discount;
            }
        }
//add hook to coupon amount hook
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5);
```

the coupon always return with 0(Zero) discount amount. Am I missing something. 
Thanks for helping =)

Answer (score 8):

Ok so this topic lead me on the road to making my own coupon type so I thought I should answer it to help others.

I tried out your code and was wondering why any normal coupon showed "-£xx" before the remove button, but the custom coupon type just was lank, no minus, no pound sign jut empty. Turns out it's an issue with how WooCommerce validates the coupon on cart products. It will become active if the coupon is valid regardless if the item in the cart are.

Your coupon needs to be either valid and valid for a product, or valid for the entire cart. However when Woocommerce checks to see if your product is valid for the product it ONLY checks if the coupon type is `fixed_product` or 'percent_product'. If it's anything else it runs the `woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product` hook with the existing data but defaulting to false, so your `woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount` hook will not fire.

So you need to hook into `woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product` and validate the product to make sure it's valid. In my case I just copied the default valid function and changes `$this` to `$coupon`.

```
// Check if coupon is valid for product
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product', 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product', 10, 4);

function woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product($valid, $product, $coupon, $values){
    if ( ! $coupon->is_type( array( 'bogof' ) ) ) {
        return $valid;
    }

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat', array( "fields" => "ids" ) );

    var_dump( $coupon->product_ids );

    // Specific products get the discount
    if ( sizeof( $coupon->product_ids ) > 0 ) {
        if ( in_array( $product->id, $coupon->product_ids ) || ( isset( $product->variation_id ) && in_array( $product->variation_id, $coupon->product_ids ) ) || in_array( $product->get_parent(), $coupon->product_ids ) ) {
            $valid = true;
        }
    }

    // Category discounts
    if ( sizeof( $coupon->product_categories ) > 0 ) {
        if ( sizeof( array_intersect( $product_cats, $coupon->product_categories ) ) > 0 ) {
            $valid = true;
        }
    }

    if ( ! sizeof( $coupon->product_ids ) && ! sizeof( $coupon->product_categories ) ) {
        // No product ids - all items discounted
        $valid = true;
    }

    // Specific product ID's excluded from the discount
    if ( sizeof( $coupon->exclude_product_ids ) > 0 ) {
        if ( in_array( $product->id, $coupon->exclude_product_ids ) || ( isset( $product->variation_id ) && in_array( $product->variation_id, $coupon->exclude_product_ids ) ) || in_array( $product->get_parent(), $coupon->exclude_product_ids ) ) {
            $valid = false;
        }
    }

    // Specific categories excluded from the discount
    if ( sizeof( $coupon->exclude_product_categories ) > 0 ) {
        if ( sizeof( array_intersect( $product_cats, $coupon->exclude_product_categories ) ) > 0 ) {
            $valid = false;
        }
    }

    // Sale Items excluded from discount
    if ( $coupon->exclude_sale_items == 'yes' ) {
        $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();

        if ( isset( $product->variation_id ) ) {
            if ( in_array( $product->variation_id, $product_ids_on_sale, true ) ) {
                $valid = false;
            }
        } elseif ( in_array( $product->id, $product_ids_on_sale, true ) ) {
            $valid = false;
        }
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question may be a little old, but there are two main coupon types, and you should add another filter based on the coupon you're adding. The filter for `woocommerce_cart_coupon_types` is for cart discounts, while `woocommerce_product_coupon_types` is for product discounts.

What you want to use is the second one `woocommerce_product_coupon_types` when you want WooCommerce to automatically validate the product/category_in and product/category_exclude fields etc.

You can still use the answer submitted by Chris for any manual validation, without using the above filters as required, however, please note that there are two validation functions to use/filter: `$coupon->is_valid_for_cart()` and `$coupon->is_valid_for_product()`.