# Custom Coupon type woocommerce wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to create custom coupon type. Because i had custom calculation for custom coupon. Anyone out there help me.

Coupon calculation:
the cart has one product and value is 5000, then custom coupon code applied. The cart total need to change 2000. Similarly the cart has 2 product and value is 7000. If the custom coupon code applied, then cart total need to be 4000.

So the coupon need to make the cart total as flat 2000 for one product

Comment: coupon appiled if one product then it has 3000 deduction and if two product then 1500 for each product right? so 3000 is flat discount right?

Comment: No if one product and total is anything i.e(5000, 4000, 8000). If coupon applied cart total need to change 2000. if product count increased, then coupon value is total = no_of_product * 2000

Comment: Kindly, try to reword your question as what you are asking is not understandable… So your question is unclear for now. Please remember that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service, so you should search a little before and try to make some code that you should provide in your question.

Comment: I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). *Please edit your post accordingly*

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of WooCommerce, you will need to

1. Register a custom coupon type
2. Validate the coupon
3. Calculate & Apply the discount

#### Register custom coupon type

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_discount_types', 'custom_coupon_type',10, 1);
function custom_coupon_type( $discount_types ) {        
    $discount_types['my_type'] =__( 'My New Coupon Type', 'woocommerce' );  
    return $discount_types;
}
```

#### Validate the coupon

```
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product', 'validate_custom_coupon', 10, 4);
function validate_custom_coupon($valid, $product, $coupon, $values){
    if ( ! $coupon->is_type( array( 'my_type' ) ) ) {
        return $valid;
    }

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat', array( "fields" => "ids" ) );
    
    // SPECIFIC PRODUCTS ARE DISCOUNTED
    if ( sizeof( $coupon->product_ids ) > 0 ) {
        if ( in_array( $product->id, $coupon->product_ids ) || ( isset( $product->variation_id ) && in_array( $product->variation_id, $coupon->product_ids ) ) || in_array( $product->get_parent(), $coupon->product_ids ) ) {
            $valid = true;
        }
    }

    // CATEGORY DISCOUNTS
    if ( sizeof( $coupon->product_categories ) > 0 ) {
        if ( sizeof( array_intersect( $product_cats, $coupon->product_categories ) ) > 0 ) {
            $valid = true;
        }
    }

    // IF ALL ITEMS ARE DISCOUNTED
    if ( ! sizeof( $coupon->product_ids ) && ! sizeof( $coupon->product_categories ) ) {            
        $valid = true;
    }
    
    // SPECIFIC PRODUCT IDs EXLCUDED FROM DISCOUNT
    if ( sizeof( $coupon->exclude_product_ids ) > 0 ) {
        if ( in_array( $product->id, $coupon->exclude_product_ids ) || ( isset( $product->variation_id ) && in_array( $product->variation_id, $coupon->exclude_product_ids ) ) || in_array( $product->get_parent(), $coupon->exclude_product_ids ) ) {
            $valid = false;
        }
    }
    
    // SPECIFIC CATEGORIES EXLCUDED FROM THE DISCOUNT
    if ( sizeof( $coupon->exclude_product_categories ) > 0 ) {
        if ( sizeof( array_intersect( $product_cats, $coupon->exclude_product_categories ) ) > 0 ) {
            $valid = false;
        }
    }

    // SALE ITEMS EXCLUDED FROM DISCOUNT
    if ( $coupon->exclude_sale_items == 'yes' ) {
        $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();

        if ( isset( $product->variation_id ) ) {
            if ( in_array( $product->variation_id, $product_ids_on_sale, true ) ) {
                $valid = false;
            }
        } elseif ( in_array( $product->id, $product_ids_on_sale, true ) ) {
            $valid = false;
        }
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

#### Calculate & Apply Discount

```
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'wc_cpn_disc', 10, 5);
function wc_cpn_disc($discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon) {
    // IF TYPE MATCHES PERFORM CUSTOM CALCULATION
    if ($coupon->type == 'my_type')
        $discount = $cart_item['quantity'] * 2000;        
    
    return $discount;
}
```

---

Sources:

- [@raju_odi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3544926/raju-odi) answer on [this exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52874952/2073738)
- [@Chris Morris's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2028904/chris-morris) answer to [Woocommerce custom coupon type with custom discount always return 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35069213/2073738)

Comment: The validation chunk can be replaced with 
```add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_coupon_types', 'add_custom_product_coupon_types', 10);
function add_custom_product_coupon_types($types){
    $types[] = 'my_type';
    return $types;
}```

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code in your active theme's function.php

```
function custom_discount_type( $discount_types ) {
    $discount_types['custom_discount'] =__( 'custom discount', 'woocommerce' );
    return $discount_types;
    }

// add the hooks
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_discount_types', 'custom_discount_type',10, 1);

//function to get coupon amount for "custom_discount"
function woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount($discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon) {

        if ($coupon->code == 'custom'){
        //echo "yes custom discount"; //if $coupon->type == 'fixed_cart' or 'percent' or 'fixed_product' or 'percent_product' The code Works
            $discount = $cart_item['quantity'] * 2000;
            return $discount;
            } else {
             return $discount;
            }
        }
//add hook to coupon amount hook
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 10, 5);
```

Note : Please add your added coupon name here on this line `if ($coupon->code == 'your_added_coupon_here')`

Working fine and tested.