# How to add new option in Discount type woo commerce Coupon module

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[image: How to add this option in discount type1]

If I choose Fixed product price and enter a Coupon amount each product should have its price set to that price.

Example : suppose we have a product that costs $100 each. Then I add the OFFER-20 coupon and use the Fixed product price discount type. Then I change the coupon amount to $20. If an user adds 3 products to the shopping cart, each product will cost $100 and the total will be $300. When the user applies the OFFER-20 coupon, each product should change to $20 and the total amount should be $60

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_coupon_discount_types` action hook for new discount type. check the below code. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function custom_discount_type( $discount_types ) {
    $discount_types['fixed_product_price'] = __( 'Fixed product price', 'woocommerce' );
    return $discount_types;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_discount_types', 'custom_discount_type', 10, 1 );
```

Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick replay, This option showing for me and how to override fix price Coupon amount.

Comment: Ok but my question is suppose we have a product that costs $100 each. Then I add the OFFER-20 coupon and use the Fixed product price discount type. Then I change the coupon amount to $20. If an user adds 3 products to the shopping cart, each product will cost $100 and the total will be $300. When the user applies the OFFER-20 coupon, each product should change to $20 and the total amount should be $60

Comment: See more here - [Custom Coupon type woocommerce Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874269/custom-coupon-type-woocommerce-wordpress/52874952)